# Distinguish user camera events in Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

Is there a way, to find was camera move caused by `ScreenSpaceCameraController` or by calling to any camera change methods such as `flyTo`?

There is a way to edit `ScreenSpaceCameraController` add some event, like `onZoom`, `onTilt`, `onTranslate` and `onModify` but is there any way to do that without Cesium modification?